# python command in php system()

Tags: php, python, system, mailman

I'm trying to write php code to change the description name of mailman's mailing list automatically using the php's system() function. But I don't know how can I do.

```
<?php
system('bin/withlist -l market
m.description = 'NewName'
m.Save()
exit()');
?>
```

Here is the command line commands to change the description name:

```
$ bin/withlist -l market
>>> m.description = 'NewName'
>>> m.Save()
>>> exit()
```

Please help me

Comment: ... Your lack of quote-escaping in your string aside, what is your question exactly? Did you run into errors?

Answer (score 1):

`system()` runs it all as one command. You're looking for something allowing you to pass input, such as `popen()`.

Here's an example:

```
if ($handle = popen('bin/withlist -l market', 'w')) {
    fwrite($handle, "m.description = 'NewName'\n");
    fwrite($handle, "m.Save()\n");
    fwrite($handle, "exit()\n");
    pclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: Thanks lunixbochs. I've tried your code, but there is an error: `Loading list market (locked)
The variable 'm' is the market MailList instance
  File "<console>", line 1
    m.Save()\nexit()\n
                     ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Unlocking (but not saving) list: market
Finalizing
>>> >>> >>>`

Answer (score 0):

You can using `<<<` and `py_eval()` function to run python code.

More information: http://www.csh.rit.edu/~jon/projects/pip/